# Django Form ChoiceField set choices in View in Form initial

Tags: python, django

This is the form

```
class Form(Models.Form):
    title = forms.ChoiceField()
```

I need to set choice values in title field according to what i get in queryset, how can it be done??

```
def func(request):
    titles = Titel.objects.all() 
    form = Form(initial={ "title": "???titles???"})
    return render('template.html', locals())
```

Answer (score 12):

```
form = Form()
form.fields['title'].choices = [(title.title, title.title) for title in titles]
form.fields['title'].initial = titles[0].title  # by default first will be selected
```

So it will return list containing tuples like

```
[('title1', 'title1'), (title2, title2), ... , ('title(n)', 'title(n)'),]
```

For your dropdown you will have this kind of select option

```
<option value="title1">title1</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use *empty_label* parameter in *form.ModelChoiceField()*

`title = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=.... , empty_label="YOUR_DEFAULT_TITLE")`