# Django Form ChoiceField pass parameter for database query

Tags: python, django, forms, class

I want to create a Django Form ChoiceField. The choices will be queried from an external database and should be filtered by a parameter {company_id}. How to pass this parameter?

views.py

```py
if request.method == 'GET':
            
   company_id = 1
   site_id = 3
            
   return render(request, 'sites/new-column.html',
                          {
                              'company_id': company_id,
                              'site_id': site_id,
                              'form_newcolumn': NewColumn(company_id),
                          })
```

forms.py

```py
class NewColumn(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        company_id = kwargs.pop('company_id')
        super(NewColumn, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
        self.company_id = company_id  # Add it as an instance variable

    engine = db.engine("Database")
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '{company_id}' ; ")
    all_rows = cursor.fetchall()

    choices = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(row[0], row[1]) for row in all_rows],
        help_text='Make your Choice'
    )
```

How to pass {company_id} to query only the necessary choices?

Comment: Do you have a predetermined list of choices?. In case of predetermined choices, you can try some conditional statements for your selection based on the value of the dependent variable ('company_id')

Comment: Yes, a predefined list in a database table. This table should be filtered by the value 'company_id' as shown in the SELECT statement, but did not know how to pass this parameter from from views.py

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for me at:

[Django Form ChoiceField set choices in View in Form initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893324/django-form-choicefield-set-choices-in-view-in-form-initial)

I put the select statement an set the form "choices" and "initial" in views.py without using any def **init** in class definition.